# Why a HTTP(S) monitoring tool is able to decode HTTPS requests and responses?

Tags: c#, security, url, post, https

I have a C# Desktop Application that sends a POST HTTPS request to a specific URL. I was wondering if the full URL can be seen by the monitoring tools. HTTPS is a secure protocol which encrypts the URL.

[image: Monitoring Image]

Why is the URL visible easily in a HTTP monitoring tool ?
In the header I see the full URL in the Request, the text HTTP/1.1, in the Content section, I can see all parameters not encrypted, plain name and values. I expected the parameters to be encrypted too.

I know that the domain name cannot be encrypted because of the DNS, but I am talking about the rest.

Comment: Presumably, your HTTP monitoring tool works as a proxy and also installs a trusted certificate so it can decrypt all traffic.

Comment: @Dai: Yes, the monitoring tool asked me for a certificate. Can you please detail how this proxy works in this context ? In such case, why use a https instead of http if there is a method to see all the content ?

Comment: @Filburt: Actually not, my question is why all my https requsts are visible in a monitoring tool if they are encrypted according to the https.

Comment: @azzido They're encrypted, yes - but they're encrypted with a certificate belonging to your HTTP monitoring tool (because you added it as a trusted cert), that's why it can decrypt everything.

Comment: They are. _You_ enabled your monitoring tool to act as a man-in-the-middle. And if you have a reasonable interest in doing so, that's correct. What worth would a monitoring tool have if it only could tell you "something has been sent somewhere"?

Comment: @Dai How the encryption certificate is selected  and when ? I thought that the C# application requests its own encryption and other tools cannot control what certificate to use. Actually, how the http monitoring tool can decide what certificate my C# application to use ?

Comment: @Fildor How the tool can influence which certificate to use by another process ? once the SSL encryption is between TCP and HTTP layer.

Comment: _"Yes, the monitoring tool asked me for a certificate."_ - when it did, it registered that and itself to be used in your local network stack.

Comment: @azzido There are multiple approaches that can be used - you haven't told us the name of the tool you're using so I can't know for certain, but I'll bet it's registering itself as a systemwide HTTP proxy in Windows: so any application that respects Windows' HTTP Proxy settings (including `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpClient` in .NET) will have its traffic intercepted, but programs that use their own low-level HTTP client won't be intercepted - unless this monitoring tool also adds a low-level packet-sniffer (but it wouldn't have the private-key to decrypt comms until after-the-fact)

Comment: I took a look at [the "HTTP Debugger" tool](https://www.httpdebugger.com/) you seem to be using - I did a quick static analysis of it and it looks like they're using [NetFilter](https://netfiltersdk.com/nfsdk.html), which in-turn uses [Windows' built-in network interception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page) library/driver `FWPKCLNT.SYS` to do most of the heavy-lifting.

Comment: @Dai Okay. In such case, an application what uses HTTPS requests can be easily monitored to see full url and parameters. Is there any way to send HTTPS requests from C# without being intercepted (not through FWPKCLNT.SYS) ?

Comment: @azzido Yes-and-no: it isn't practical for a C# program to avoid going through Windows' Winsock network stack, which means a C# program's traffic can always be intercepted (but not necessarily decrypted) by any monitoring tool using the Windows Filtering Platform, but provided the C# program uses _certificate-pinning_ techniques then the C# program can simply refuse to work until it's able to confirm there's no MITM attack being used - of course, C# programs are trivial to edit (e.g. to disable certificate-pinning) so I'm curious what you're _really_ trying to do here...

Comment: @azzido The other explanations regarding your usage of a monitoring tool aside, the linked post explains *"... the domain name part of the URL is sent in clear text during the first part of the TLS negotiation"*.

Comment: @Dai What I want to achieve is to hide the files that are called on the server. For example: if the request is to https://www.example.com/DoSomething then I want to hide "DoSomething" part. I don't care if the domain name is visible. The Post requests contain also parameters but they are encrypted by my own method, so, they are more or less secured.

Comment: @Filburt Yes, I know that domain name cannot be encrypted, I am fine with that, but I want to hide the rest of the link. Let's say you have an https request from a desktop application, you don't want to have the link visible just by easy monitoring stuff. Think, the link can be used for a DDoS attack.

Comment: @azzido You can't "hide" things like that. What problem are you actually trying to solve? Why not use one-time-use URIs instead?

Comment: @Dai Let's say you have a secret algo that receives a seed and computes a key. The secret algo is implemented in the secret.php file. The desktop app has to call the secret algo using https request, so a call to https://www.example.com/secret.php . Monitoring the traffic you know the secret link at least, let's say the input/output can be encrypted by yourself. But this is not sufficient, the same request with encrypted parameters can be replicated, this is one issue. The other one, is DDoS attack, knowing the link you can do a DDoS attack.

Comment: @azzido _"Monitoring the traffic you know the secret link at least"_ - **you're doing it wrong**: if you were to use a proper key-exchange protocol, such as _Diffie–Hellman_ (which is designed to work when two parties communicate over an insecure channel) then there wouldn't be any actual secrets exposed at all, even with all HTTPS traffic revealed in the clear.

Comment: @azzido _"The other one, is DDoS attack, knowing the link you can do a DDoS attack."_ - Again, _you're doing it wrong_: you seem to be relying on [Security through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) - which simply doesn't work. Also, a key-generation algo will only be susceptible to DDoS attacks if it's somehow incredibly inefficient, whereas consider that your computer likely generates dozens of new keys _every second_ simply when using HTTPS for normal web-traffic.... So if someone can bring your entire site down by spamming a single request that's on you.

Comment: @azzido Only if you take me out for a nice cocktail and dinner first

Comment: @Dai Done. Please delete it.

Comment: @Dai Message sent.

Comment: @Dai Have you got my message ? I am not from the USA, I wanted to take you to dinner.

Comment: @azzido I'm still a week behind on my emails - I'll get to it eventually

Comment: @Dai Ok, I am waiting :)

Comment: @azzido What was the subject-line of the email? And you're prepared to see my rate card?

Comment: Email subject is: "azzido from stackoverflow - HTTP requests from C#"